# xsd same element, different types?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a situation where an element in the XML-file can be of two different types in the XSD.

What I want to do is first to validate the entered value to the more strict type (if it's a person that fills out the form) and if that doesn't pull through, validate it to the lesser strict type (if it's an organization that fills out the form), otherwise let the validation fail if it doesn't validate at all.

So this is basically it:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ForminfoType"> `
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="formname" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="timestamp" type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element name="sender" type="PersonType" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="receiver" type="OrganizationType" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="signature" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

What the PersonType declares is basically a 12-digit number constructed according to a specific pattern. What the Organization type declares is basically just a 10-digit number.

So what I logically would like to do is to put this:

```
<xsd:element name="sender" type="OrganizationType" minOccurs="0" />
```

into the sequence, but you can't have two elements with the same name and different types. So I reckon I must solve it in some other way.

What I have found was this:
http://xsd.stylusstudio.com/2007Oct/post05003.htm

Which is pretty much what I want to do, but I'm not sure it's possible. 
Has anyone got any further ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to use the backticks for multi-lines of code. Just select the lines and use Control-K.

Comment: @Arizon: to format code properly, highlight it and then click on the button with the zeroes and ones (01010 0101010) in the toolbar above the editor!

Answer (score 17):

No, you can't really do this. One option you have it to create a "PersonOrOrgSender" complex type along the lines of :

```
  <xsd:complexType name="PersonOrOrgType">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="PersonSender" type="PersonType" />
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="OrgSender" type="OrganizationType" />
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

and then make your "sender" an instance of that type:

```
<xsd:element name="sender" type="PersonOrOrgType" minOccurs="0" />
```

but then you'll have XML data like this:

```
<FormInfo>
  <formname>string</formname>
  <sender>
    <OrgSender>
      <Name>string</Name>
    </OrgSender>
  </sender>  
  ...
</FormInfo>
```

or

```
<FormInfo>
  <formname>string</formname>
  <sender>
    <PersonSender>
      <Name>string</Name>
    </PersonSender>
  </sender>  
  ...
</FormInfo>
```

You cannot make a single tag (e.g. "sender") be one thing in one case and another in a different case - one tag must have exactly one well-defined type and has that type once and for all times.

Marc

Comment: Marc, Thank you very much, unfortunately I ran into another problem, The sender element was not allowed to have a child node, so I solved it by adding an "or" and the organization pattern to the PersonType.
"|[0-9]{10}"
 regards, Erik

Answer (score 1):

Given your issues with the solution provided by @mark_s, you have several options:

- Create two separate XSDs with the two types for `sender`.  In your code that triggers the validation, run them sequentially (i.e. person then organization).  This has the added benefit that your code will know which validation passed (and could make choices based on that knowledge).
- (Commenters report this does not work) <s>Move the choice up a level within the XSD.  Inside `ForminfoType`, add a choice node with two sequences (one person, one organization).  I haven't validated, but roughly:</s>

  ```
   <xsd:complexType name="ForminfoType">
       <xsd:choice>
           <xsd:sequence> <!-- person -->
               <xsd:element name="formname" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="timestamp" type="xsd:dateTime" />
               <xsd:element name="sender" type="PersonType" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="receiver" type="OrganizationType" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="signature" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
           </xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:sequence> <!-- organization -->
               <xsd:element name="formname" type="xsd:string" />
               <xsd:element name="timestamp" type="xsd:dateTime" />
               <xsd:element name="sender" type="OrganizationType" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="receiver" type="OrganizationType" minOccurs="0" />
               <xsd:element name="signature" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
           </xsd:sequence>
       </xsd:choice>
   </xsd:complexType>
  ```

Comment: The choice of sequences you suggest is invalid.  You will get an error like this: `Elements with the same name and in the same scope must have the same type.`

Comment: Also if you didn't have a type you would get an error like this: `Multiple definitions of element 'sender' causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly, or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence`.

Answer (score 1):

Although a very old post but this might help someone.

You can achieve this by subtyping and then using xsi:type attribute in your XML. You can refer to the below link for the details and examples.

[Subtyping and xsi:type](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-schema-tutorial/xsd-extending-types#xsi-type)