# Xerces-J XSD 1.1 validation with unrestricted XPath processing of Assertions/Alternatives

Tags: xml, assertions, xerces, xsd-1.1

The [Using XML Schemas](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xs.html#faq-2]) page (on the Apache XML Project website) states:

> Within the type alternatives implementation, Xerces-J first attempts to compile the XPath expression with a native Xerces "XPath subset" parser. If parsing with the native Xerces "XPath subset" parser fails, Xerces-J transparently switches over to another processor which supports all of XPath 2.0. The native processor in Xerces-J was written for efficiency, so you will likely get better performance if your XPath expressions fall within the minimum subset defined by the XML Schema 1.1 specification. For full XPath 2.0 evaluation (for XSD 1.1 'assertions', and optionally for 'type alternatives'), Xerces-J uses the Eclipse/PsychoPath XPath 2.0 engine.

This paragraph implies that the **test** of an **assert** or **alternative** need not be restricted to the XPath limitations imposed by the XSD 1.1 standard, provided that one's executable incorporates the PyschoPath XPath processor.

Using the following command line:

`$ export XERCESJ=$HOME/xerces-j/xerces-2_11_0-xml-schema-1.1-beta
$ java -classpath $XERCESJ/cupv10k-runtime.jar:$PSYCHOPATH/psychopath.jar:/usr/share/java/org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor-2.1.100.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl-xsd11-2.12-beta-r1667115.jar:$XERCESJ/xml-apis.jar:$XERCESJ/xercesSamples.jar jaxp.SourceValidator -xsd11 -i my_instance.xml`

I have tried each of the following XPath expressions in my **alternative**s' **test**s:

1. `<alternative test="@value='4567'" ... />`
2. `<alternative test="../Sibling/@value='1234'" ... />`

The 1st (trivial) **test** expression *succeeds*, but the 2nd (non-trivial) **test** expression *fails* with:

`c-cta-xpath: The XPath expression '../Sibling/@value='1234'' couldn't compile successfully in 'cta-subset' mode, during CTA evaluation.`

Moreover, I believe that my inclusion of the PsychoPath XPath processor has had *no effect*, because I see *exactly* the same behavior whether I include or remove PsychoPath from the **classpath**. If I remove only the Eclipse (WST) XPath processor, then I get a *missing class* exception.

I have seen an [old Apache issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1533) that references a **cta-full-xpath-checking** feature that must be explicitly enabled, but the above quote clearly indicates that

> ... Xerces-J **transparently** [my emphasis] switches over to another processor which supports all of XPath 2.0.

I want an XML Schema 1.1 **alternative** element to perform a **test** on the attribute of a parent element, or on the attribute of a sibling element. What modifications to my approach will achieve this goal?

Comment: I don't know exactly what's going on here, but the expression `'../Sibling/@value='1234'` is never going to be useful in a type alternative, whatever subset of XPath 2.0 is chosen, because the context item for evaluating the expression will always be a parentless element. (XSD 1.1 part 1 §3.12.4 rule 1.2)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You are correct -- I want non-standard behavior w.r.t. evaluation of the **test** expression -- but I interpret the quote to mean exactly that. Please see the answer from @Alexander to a related question: [XML Schema for Tagged Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356007/xml-schema-for-tagged-union). There, you can see that Alexander has proposed essentially the same _non-standard_ XPath expression. I'm trying to prove this usage before committing myself to XSD 1.1.

Comment: I have no idea whether Xerces supports such a non-standard mode of operation, but all the information cited is about the XPath language level, not about non-standard ways of setting the context for XPath evaluation. XSD validation is supposed to be context-independant: the validity of an element does not depend on its parent or siblings. If you're trying to get around that, I hope you find that it isn't possible.